# How to format selected date column as relative time format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

If we have a table with timestamp field, I would like to display the dates as `time ago`
(something similar to the way we do in Java/PHP)

Is there a ready function which does the job esp in MySQL?

The Output should be relative time instead of usual date-time eg `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

```
    USER    |    LAST_LOGGED_IN
_____________________________________
    ABC     |    5 minutes ago
_____________________________________
    PQR     |    10 minutes ago
_____________________________________
    XYZ     |    2 weeks ago
_____________________________________
    XXX     |    1 month ago
```

Comment: You can use [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: @HoneyBadger, can you show how? btw I edited my question a little bit for clarity

Comment: You'd be much better off playing with that function for a bit yourself. You'll probably need a `case` expression as well. When are you going from minutes to hours, or from days to weeks, will you be rounding? All these questions are much easier solved by yourself while attempting to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use timestampdiff function:

```
select       
t.userid,     
case when t.years > 0 
     then concat( t.years ,' year', case when t.years > 1
                                         then 's' else '' end, ' ago')  
     when t.months > 0         
     then concat( t.months, ' month', case when t.months > 1    
                                           then 's' else '' end, ' ago')
     when t.weeks > 0 
     then concat( t.weeks , ' week', case when t.weeks > 1 
                                          then 's' else '' end, ' ago')  
     when t.days > 0  
     then concat( t.days , ' day', case when t.days > 1 
                                        then 's' else '' end, ' ago')  
     when t.hours > 0 
     then concat( t.hours, ' hour',  case when t.hours > 1 
                                          then 's' else '' end, ' ago')  
     when t.minutes > 0
     then concat( t.minutes, ' minute', case when t.minutes > 1  
                                          then 's' else '' end, ' ago')    
     else concat( t.seconds, ' second', case when t.seconds > 1
                                          then 's' else '' end, ' ago')
end as last_login  
from  
(  
select   
    userid,   
    timestampdiff(second, login_time, now()) as seconds,  
    timestampdiff(minute, login_time, now()) as minutes,  
    timestampdiff(hour, login_time,now()) as hours,  
    timestampdiff(day, login_time,now()) as days,  
    timestampdiff(week, login_time,now()) as weeks,  
    timestampdiff(month, login_time, now()) as months,  
    timestampdiff(year, login_time, now()) as years 
from user_login ) t
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2cbee/5

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's useful. I'd like to convert the answer into a function so that it will be reusable

Comment: Glad that helps :)